# stick navbar to centered image

Tags: html, css, center, responsive

i want to make a centered resized image+ navigation bar in a webpage with header and footer, header fixed top, footer fixed buttom, and image and the navbar, together should be resizable, **respecting the aspect ration of the image** (image could shrink, but never bypass original size.

**the image is done, behaving as wanted!**

the problem i had, i **couldn't make the navigation bar stick in the bottom of the image as it's resized!**

here is my code: https://codepen.io/chlegou/pen/vvYzya

```
<div class="popup">

    <img class="image" src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-h2cD5VqGNGk/U1t6QX7kY5I/AAAAAAAAFvc/46BsvAWjmSw/w640-h360-no/IMG_2061+SCR.jpg" />
    <span class="content">

        <span class="navbar">Navigation Bar</span>

    </span>
</div>
```

i want the popup content stick together, with the image dynamic width. **image still could shrink as it is! fix only the navbar to follow the image and stick to it.**

thanks!

Comment: what is issue? please show with picture.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED** the styling as you needed please check the codepen:https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZVOoqq

```
<div class="outer-container">
   <div class="inner-container">
       <img class="image" src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-h2cD5VqGNGk/U1t6QX7kY5I/AAAAAAAAFvc/46BsvAWjmSw/w640-h360-no/IMG_2061+SCR.jpg"/>
       <div class="centered-content">
          <span style="overflow: hidden">Navigation Bar</span>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

and the for the styling of the divs please refer the codepen given above

Comment: not that, i want when resizing the webpage, the navigation always sticks to the image, just below it always!

Comment: So you want the <span class="navbar">Navigation Bar</span> to move along with the image when resizing right???

Comment: Please check the https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bOEZpV edited codepen hope this is what needed just move into div instead of span

Comment: that's fantastic! exactly how it needed to behave! :D now could we make navigation be the same width like the image? (same as image, if image shrink, navigation menu shrink, till get the min-width)

Comment: also make the image and the navigation menu always centered. they are kind of sticking at the top.

Comment: Image and navigation always centered check this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GPqEMe you just need to change some styles in .popup and .footer check it out!!!

Comment: the page shouldn't have a scrollbar, as made in original file

Comment: Since you have used z-index for fixing the page without a scroll bar if i am trying to centre the image the scroll bar is coming and the footer is going up thats why I restyled the footer so if you dont want the scroll .... i think centering it will be trouble without scroll but you can do something like this by adding for content before image like this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZVOJYv

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZVOoqq Please check this updated codepen for desired styling in centre

Comment: Did you check the latest updated codepen?? @HoussemChlegou

Comment: not like desired, but i'm satisfied with what we have got. thanks!